# Getting values corresponding to start date and end date

Tags: sql-server

I have table of the following form

```
Name    Currency    Rate    Effective date
Institution 1   USD 0.25    Sunday, June 05, 2016
Institution 1   CAD 0.35    Monday, December 05, 2016
Institution 1   USD 0.5 Monday, April 03, 2017
Institution 2   USD 0.25    Sunday, August 07, 2016
Institution 2   USD 0.28    Sunday, January 15, 2017
Institution 2   CAD 0.35    Saturday, April 20, 2013
Institution 2   CAD 0.25    Monday, March 06, 2017
```

I need a query in SQL Server grouped for each institution and currency, get the rate for effective date between start date and end date. If there is no effective date between declared start date and end date then look for the last effective date lower than start date and get the corresponding rate e.g. If start date is Jan 1, 2017 and end date is Mar 31, 2017 then for Institution 1, USD Rate will be 0.25 and CAD Rate will 0.35. Similarly for start date Apr 1, 2017 and end date May 31, 2017 USD Rate will be 0.5 and CAD Rate will be 0.35.

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: What does your current query look like?

Comment: In future note you are expected to at least try a query and include it in the question. Also please learn how to present fixed width data correctly *(there is a toolbar you can use)* and for dates in sample data please don't use day and month names.

Comment: I will make sure to include my query in the question. Also will not include the day and month names for sample data . But I am not sure about the toolbar. Will try to make it better next time.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you can query as below:

```
Select * from (
     Select Name,   Currency,   Rate,   [Effective date],
        RowN = Row_Number() over (Partition by [Name], [Currency] Order by [Effective Date] desc)
     from yourTable 
     where [Effective Date] between @startDate and @EndDate ) a
    where a.RowN = 1
```

In other ways

```
 Select top (1) with ties 
     Name,  Currency,   Rate,   [Effective date]
     from yourTable
     Where [Effective Date] between @startDate and @EndDate
     Order by Row_Number() over (Partition by [Name], [Currency] Order by [Effective Date] desc)
```

Both works in same logic.

But this does not cover your requirement "If there is no effective date between declared start date and end date then look for the last effective date lower than start date" as it is not clear to me. Can you show more samples to that..

Comment: One of the examples could be, if start date is April 10,2017 and end date is May 31,2017 in that case for Institution 1, CAD Rate should be 0.35 as there is no eff date between start date and end date Also for USD rate it will look at the effective dates and since April 03,2017 comes after June 05,2016 it should take rate of 0.5 corresponding to Apr 3, for USD and not rate of 0.25

Answer (score 0):

The use of ROW_NUMBER() and OVER() is an efficient way to determine "most recent" or "latest" rows. Inside the OVER clause it is the **ORDER BY ... DESC** which locates the "latest" information.

In this question the need for this to be within a date range is a little misleading because all that is required is that the effective date is before the end date of that range, so: *less than end date* covers all wanted results as shown below.

sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([Name] varchar(12), [Currency] varchar(3), [Rate] decimal(12,2), [EffectiveDate] datetime)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([Name], [Currency], [Rate], [EffectiveDate])
VALUES
    ('Institution1', 'USD', 0.25, '2016-06-05 00:00:00'),
    ('Institution1', 'CAD', 0.35, '2016-12-05 00:00:00'),
    ('Institution1', 'USD', 0.5, '2017-04-03 00:00:00'),
    ('Institution2', 'USD', 0.25, '2016-08-07 00:00:00'),
    ('Institution2', 'USD', 0.28, '2017-01-15 00:00:00'),
    ('Institution2', 'CAD', 0.35, '2013-04-20 00:00:00'),
    ('Institution2', 'CAD', 0.25, '2017-03-06 00:00:00')
;
```

**Query 1**

```
declare @EndDate as datetime 
set @EndDate = '20170331'

SELECT
      *
FROM (
      SELECT
            Name
          , Currency
          , Rate
          , EffectiveDate
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name, Currency ORDER BY EffectiveDate DESC) AS rn
          , @EndDate EndDate
      FROM Table1
      WHERE EffectiveDate < @EndDate
      ) AS d
WHERE d.rn = 1
;
```

**Result 1**

```
/*
If start date is Jan 1, 2017 and end date is Mar 31, 2017 
then for Institution 1, USD Rate will be 0.25 and CAD Rate will 0.35.
*/
+----+--------------+----------+------+---------------+----+------------+
|    |     Name     | Currency | Rate | EffectiveDate | rn |  EndDate   |
+----+--------------+----------+------+---------------+----+------------+
|  1 | Institution1 | CAD      | 0.35 | 05/12/2016    |  1 | 31/03/2017 |
|  2 | Institution1 | USD      | 0.25 | 05/06/2016    |  1 | 31/03/2017 |
|  3 | Institution2 | CAD      | 0.25 | 06/03/2017    |  1 | 31/03/2017 |
|  4 | Institution2 | USD      | 0.28 | 15/01/2017    |  1 | 31/03/2017 |
+----+--------------+----------+------+---------------+----+------------+
```

**Query 2**

```
set @EndDate = '20170531'

SELECT
      *
FROM (
      SELECT
            Name
          , Currency
          , Rate
          , EffectiveDate
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name, Currency ORDER BY EffectiveDate DESC) AS rn
          , @EndDate EndDate
      FROM Table1
      WHERE EffectiveDate < @EndDate
      ) AS d
WHERE d.rn = 1
;
```

**Result 2**

```
/*
Similarly for start date Apr 1, 2017 and end date May 31, 2017 
USD Rate will be 0.5 and CAD Rate will be 0.35.
*/
+----+--------------+----------+------+---------------+----+------------+
|    |     Name     | Currency | Rate | EffectiveDate | rn |  EndDate   |
+----+--------------+----------+------+---------------+----+------------+
|  1 | Institution1 | CAD      | 0.35 | 05/12/2016    |  1 | 31/05/2017 |
|  2 | Institution1 | USD      | 0.50 | 03/04/2017    |  1 | 31/05/2017 |
|  3 | Institution2 | CAD      | 0.25 | 06/03/2017    |  1 | 31/05/2017 |
|  4 | Institution2 | USD      | 0.28 | 15/01/2017    |  1 | 31/05/2017 |
+----+--------------+----------+------+---------------+----+------------+
```